# Matlab: colorbar of contourplot only for specified contour levels

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, contourf

I plotted a contour plot in Matlab with data stored in in A, B and C.

`contourf(A,B,C,'LineColor','none')`

The data stored in C contains values which are 1, 45, 600 and 1000. So the contour plot has only 4 different contour levels. So far as good.

No my issue: I want to show a colorbar with only the 4 contour levels and only the particular colors for 1, 45, 600 and 1000. Therefore I used the code:

`colorbar('Ticks',[1,45,600,1000]);`

Unfortunatly, Matlab is now plotting a gradient colorbar from 0 to 1000 (gradient colors) and shows only the ticks defined in the code above at the position between 0 and 1000.

How can I get a colorbar showing only the 4 contour levels without a colorgradient?

Thanks in advance!

I plotted a contour plot and the respective colorbar. I changed different settings of the colorbar but the gradient is still visible.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] which we might copy/paste/adapt to show you potential solutions

Comment: This link might help you. https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/738107-how-to-make-a-discrete-colorbar-with-specified-intervals